# only image uploading and displaying that from database

Tags: php, mysql

Hi frnds really i dont know how to vote today i came to know,dont neglate my que thinking i have not accept...i am begginer to development i want to upload only image to database and that i need to fetch and display..i should fetch directly image and display can anyone please help me out thank in advace

Comment: You'll need to significantly clarify your question to get any helpful answers.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php) is a nice tutorial on uploading files with PHP, and [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) is a tutorial in parameterizing queries.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend storing binary data in a database. Upload your image to the filesystem and store a locationstring in your database. Then query your table, fetch the results and put `$result["location"]` in your `<img src=""/>` tag. This, of course only works when you fetch your query-result associative in `$result` and you have a column `location` in your table ;)

And you should really start giving votes and accepting answers, you've asked 27 question and none of them have an accepted answer. This makes people less willing to help you!

Answer (score 0):

Example for storage:

```
$f = file_get_contents(FILENAME);
$size = filesize(FILENAME);
$m = new mysqli(HOSTNAME,USERNAME,PASSWORD,DATABASE);
$m->query('INSERT INTO images (data,size) VALUES ("'.$m->real_escape_string($f).'",'.$size.')');
```